# How to mark cell in Excel spreadsheet as non-page-breaking?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there any way to declare a cell/row in Excel as a cell/row that should not be used for page break.

Example:

```
A1: 1. My content title in bold
A2: Empty row
A3: More and more content, description, etc...on many lines.
A4: 2. My other content title in bold
A5: Empty row
A6: More and more content, description, etc...on many lines.
```

If that goes on for many pages, I would like Excel not to break between A1 and A3, A4 and A6, etc.

Is that feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most fool-proof way will be to manually assign page breaks.  Go to:

`View->Page Break Preview`

On this view you can drag page breaks (the dotted lines) to where you want, both horizontally and vertically.  Excel will automagically adjust the size of the text/cells/etc. to fit into your specified breaks.

Comment: The problem is that the document is programmatically generated. The size of cells can change every time.

Comment: That's trickier...I don't think there will be a way to do it without a custom VBA script for this.

Comment: What would you like to determine the pagebreak? Your example seems to indicate empty intervening rows. Will you want to break following some of those, because you could set pagebreaks programatically if it is known where you want to allow it.